# How can I remove the Android Sample Soft Keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, sample

I have run the sample soft keyboard provided in the Android SDK on a real device.  I now would like to remove it from the list of available keyboards in settings.  I have searched the web without any hits.  It also shows up on one of my emulators too.

I'm sure it's probably an obvious answer, but I just can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Applications > (Find it in the list of applications) > Tap on it > Uninstall.

I think you can also uninstall through adb if you're in "USB debugging" mode.

Comment: I can't imagine this question would have 4 upvotes and no answers if it was really this easy, so perhaps I'm missing something.